# Unable to zip multiple files using Java

Tags: java, struts2, inputstream

Getting data onto inputStream object from web url

```
inputStream = AWSFileUtil.getInputStream(
                    AWSConnectionUtil.getS3Object(null),
                    "cdn.generalsentiment.com", filePath);
```

If they are mutliple files then i want to zip them and sent the filetype as "zip" to struts.xml which does the download.

actually am converting the inputstream into byteArrayInputStream

```
ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new    
ByteArrayInputStream(inputStream.toString().getBytes());
            while (byteArrayInputStream.read(inputStream.toString().getBytes()) > 0) {
                zipOutputStream.write(inputStream.toString().getBytes());
            }
```

and then

```
 zipOutputStream.close();
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        while (fileInputStream.read(buffer) > 0) {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer);
        }
        byteArrayOutputStream.close();
        inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
        reportName = "GS_MediaValue_Reports.zip";
        fileType = "zip";
    } 

    return fileType;
```

But the downloaded zip when extracted gives corrupt files.
Please suggest me a solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that it's not how [`ZipOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html) works. Since it was designed to store multiple files, along with their file names, directory structures and so on, you need to tell the stream about that explicitly.

Furthermore, converting a stream to a string is a bad idea in general, plus it's slow, especially when you're doing it in a loop.

So your solution will be something like:

```
ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry( fileName ); // You have to give each entry a different filename
zipOutputStream.putNextEntry( entry );
byte buffer[] = new byte[ 1024 ]; // 1024 is the buffer size here, but it could be anything really
int count;
while( (count = inputStream.read( buffer, 0, 1024 ) ) != -1 ) {
    zipOutputStream.write( buffer, 0, count );
}
```